# Firebase reporting GoogleTV for some iOS users

Tags: ios, firebase-analytics, google-tv

We are seeing a large percentage of our analytics report Google TV in our iOS application.  Since we in no way support Google TV, this has to be a error.

[image: Wrong model]

We have followed the firebase install, and never saw a place to force the model, does anyone know if there is somewhere we should be setting the model?

The only thing I thing might be is the Xcode simulator, curious if others are seeing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing the same when using Xcode 8.2 and iPhone Simulator. Oddly, Firebase is reporting the OS correctly (10.2)

Comment: Same issue is happing with the C++ SDK (2.1.3) of Firebase. iPhone Simulator is reporting GoogleTV and app_platform in big query is showing iOS.

Comment: Even worse, what is "Other".  So basically Firebase is accurate less than 20% of the time on something that should be exact.  Still seeing this.

Comment: Even I' m getting this, simulator is showing as Google TV

Answer (score 1):

I think `FIRDebugEnabled` or `FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled` should be enabled in the arguments when you're using a simulator.